# Mystery 1970s display type

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

In the early 1970s, ABC TV used a Kabel-like font in its advertisements in print and on the air. I've always assumed this was a custom agency font, but in my old age I'm now I'm wondering: The lowercase e is clearly designed as tilted, so was this a long-forgotten Letraset font or the invention of ABC's creative department? Or...?

[image: Here are some samples from ABC's archive.]

Comment: Please follow our [font ID requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366).

Comment: In any case, that's so recognisable -- it's [Avant Garde](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic). The *e* is one of the many variant letters.